# Is there way to pass values dynamically through array instead of using indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dom, random

[image][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7bNt.png

Right now it works like this:

1- when key's index 0 do this,
2- when key's index 1 do this,
3- when key's index 2 do this.

but I want to add min and max value for objectVal array that can fix (for stance key[min], n , key[max]) but nth values in between, like it can add new keys and values in slider dynamically instead of calling its indexs and adding new conditional operators.

````
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".allSliders");
let result = document.querySelector(".result");
let totalNumber = 0;
let values = [];
let sliderNums = [];

let objectVal = [
  {
   keys: [0, 500,1000],
    values: [0.0045,  0.0044,0.0043]
  }, 
  {
   keys: [0, 500,1000],
    values: [0.0045,  0.0044,0.0043]
  },
    {
   keys: [0, 500,1000],
    values: [0.0045,  0.0044,0.0043]
  },

]; 

sliders.forEach((sliderNumber, id) => {
  sliderNumber.addEventListener("input", () => {
    let action =
      objectVal[id].keys[3] - objectVal[id].keys[3];
    let maxLine = objectVal[id].keys[3] + action;
    let getInformation = maxLine - action * 0.666;
    sliderNumber.setAttribute("max", maxLine);

    let currentRange = parseInt(sliderNumber.value);
    sliderNums[id] = currentRange;

    function line(value, currentVal, obj) 
{
      values[id] = currentVal * obj;
      sliderNumber.nextElementSibling.querySelector(
        ".tooltiptext"
      ).textContent = `(${currentVal} * ${obj})`;
      sliderNumber.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".dollar").textContent =
       values[id].toFixed(2);
      }


    if (
      currentRange > objectVal[id].keys[0] &&
      currentRange <= objectVal[id].keys[3] ) 
      {
line(values[id], currentRange, objectVal[id].values[0])
      }
    else if (
      currentRange > objectVal[id].keys[3] &&
      currentRange <= objectVal[id].keys[3]
    ) {
     line(values[id], currentRange, objectVal[id].values[3])
    } 
    else {
      line(values[id], currentRange, objectVal[id].values[3])
    }```
````

Comment: You haven't defined `sliderNumber`, `slider`, `id`, `value`,`currentVal`, and `obj`. Your problem is vague because you describe the need for a range of values from an array(s) yet you don't want use index...what does your code do instead? It's not obvious because there are too many undefined variables.

Comment: @zer00ne I edited my code, can you look now, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.